# С++. Проблема со всем. Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Только начал программировать на C++, в итоге ничего не понять, как начать. Попытался установить на Visual Studio Code и C++, и code runner, в итоге написал простенькую программку:

input:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world bitsdsdsches!";
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\User\Desktop\разработка\C++\Коды\" && g++ beginning.cpp -o beginning && "c:\Users\User\Desktop\разработка\C++\Коды\"beginning
"g++" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.046 seconds
```

что бы я не написал в cout, всё то же самое выходит, только время выполнения программы меняется. Что делать?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Строка в С пишется в двойных кавычках.

Comment: Из обычной консоли `g++` запускается? Путь к нему записан в PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл в том, что я - дурак - не установил компилятор.

Тем, кто не понял: чтобы работать с C++ нужен компилятор. Устанавливаете g++ (gcc) и пишите на здоровье!

сайт, где я взял компилятор: http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran

Всем спасибо. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Странно, что выводит мусор - вот это

```
'Hello world bitsdsdsches!'
```

теоретически символьный литерал, который при большем размере обычно воспринимается как `int` - см., например [тут](http://ideone.com/hLp0Rz).

Visual C++ честно ругается -

> error C2015: слишком много знаков в константе

Если урезать до четырех - до `'Hell'` - то это будет воспринято как четырехбайтовый `int`, где старший байт `H` - `0x48`, следующий `e` - `0x65` и т.д. - т.е. `0x48656c6c`.

А если хотите вывести строку, то учтите, что тут не Pascal, и строки должны быть в двойных кавычках -

```
cout << "Hello world bitsdsdsches!";
```